# copy table data to a different database using stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Just wondering, im new to stored procedures,

I just tried this

```
INSERT INTO new.emp SELECT * FROM old.users
```

and it worked and inserted the data of users from the old table users to the new emp table.

But when I did that inside a stored procedure im getting a syntax error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertnew
    INSERT INTO new.emp SELECT * FROM old.users
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

In what part of the query are you getting a syntax error? The correct syntax for creating a stored procedure is something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployee()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO new.emp SELECT * FROM old.users;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I had the error on the Insert into... line. Btw, i tried this and i worked thank you! I thought I didnt need the "DELIMITER //" but looks like i need it. Btw, I have another select query that gets the data in the different tables (the tables is in the same database and im using left join to combine it all). My question is, can I just do this INSERT INTO newdb.table <Then the SELECT query that I have> Or do i need to do anything special like define some of the tables or something?

Comment: ok i just tried it and i didnt get any error, but when i try to call the procedure how come i got the error `SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'table'

Comment: The 'user' don't have a permission to use SELECT clause so you need to use this command, `USE mysql` database first and then type this query `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY <password>;` This link can help you further: http://www.databasef1.com/tutorial/mysql-create-user.html